# Solidity - Balance is zero for the deployed ERC20 contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, ganache, openzeppelin

I'm trying to create an ERC20 token using truffle and upgradable openzeppelin contracts.
The problem is that the token balance is **zero** when I add the contract address into the Metamask extension.
When I use **remix**, Everything is Ok and I can see the correct balance of the deployed contract in the Metamask.
But I don't know where is the problem when I use it in localhost using `Truffle` and `Ganache`.

**Token.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20SnapshotUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

contract Token is
  Initializable,
  ERC20Upgradeable,
  ERC20SnapshotUpgradeable,
  OwnableUpgradeable,
  PausableUpgradeable
{
  /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
  constructor() initializer {}

  function initialize() public initializer {
    __ERC20_init("Token", "TKN");
    __ERC20Snapshot_init();
    __Ownable_init();
    __Pausable_init();

    _mint(msg.sender, 10000000000 * 18**decimals());
  }

  function snapshot() public onlyOwner {
    _snapshot();
  }

  function pause() public onlyOwner {
    _pause();
  }

  function unpause() public onlyOwner {
    _unpause();
  }

  function _beforeTokenTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
  )
    internal
    override(ERC20Upgradeable, ERC20SnapshotUpgradeable)
    whenNotPaused
  {
    super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
  }
}
```

**truffle-config.js:**

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    //  test: {
    //    host: "127.0.0.1",
    //    port: 7545,
    //    network_id: "*"
    //  }
  },
```

**Metamask network config**:
[image: Metamask config]

**TKN token balance**:
[image]

Video:
https://youtu.be/HHWsnlJxZ7Y

Comment: did you solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

This code might help you i, since i have used tuffle and ganache to connect metamask locally. make sure you are using truffle hdwallet provider [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider)

```
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config({path: "./.env"});
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const AccountIndex = 0;

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      port: 7545,
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      network_id: 5777
    },
    ganache_local: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "http://127.0.0.1:7545", AccountIndex)
      },
      network_id: 5777
    },
    goerli_infura: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/ffa60321cbbd4cfda3352014c556e3c3", AccountIndex)
      },
      network_id: 5
    },
    ropsten_infura: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/ffa60321cbbd4cfda3352014c556e3c3", AccountIndex)
      },
      network_id: 3
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.1"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. the issue was not solved. 
[https://youtu.be/HHWsnlJxZ7Y](https://youtu.be/HHWsnlJxZ7Y)

Answer (score 2):

You must import the ganache `accounts[0]` to your Metamask.

When you are deploying with **Remix** and **Metamask**, deployer is your Metamask connected account, and when you are deploying `initialize` function being called and `msg.sender` is your connected account and 10000000000 token mint and transfer to that account and you can see it on your Metamask

But, when you are deploying with **Truffle** to your local **ganache**, you must get account 0 private key from ganache and import to Metamask to see that token in your wallet. If you are not provided mnemonic when running ganache, deployer(accounts[0]) in ganache every time is a newly generated address.

see this link: https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/ethereum-and-clients/ganache-cli/ check these flags `-a` accounts `-m` mnemonic

Comment: Hey @amir-habibzadeh , thanks for your response.
I have done all these steps. But the issue was not solved. I uploaded a 30-second video. Please watch this video:
[https://youtu.be/HHWsnlJxZ7Y](https://youtu.be/HHWsnlJxZ7Y) 
 (Video link was added to the question). Thank you so much.